# Is it possible to copy Promotions from one environment to other environment?

Tags: 2013-sp1, smarttarget

I am responsible to create and manage the smart target promotion in our project. We have 7 environments and more than 35 smart target promotions.

```
DEV > ST > SIT > MVP > E2E > PT > PROD
```

Now It is become difficult for me to create the Promotions to the all environments every time.

Is there any possible way to copy or Export/Import our promotions from one environment to other so that every environments should be in sync?
We are using SDL 2013 SP1 and Smart Target 2014 SP1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an option where you can replicate entire business.xml over indexers (on different instances). This is something that SDL professional services did for us. They created power shell script for exactly that. I guess that can do the job for you. We had more than 1000 promotions per environment that needed to be scaled down over environments.

Answer (score 6):

Admittedly, I haven't used this, so I can't tell you if it covers *exactly* what you're trying to do... but have you checked [this chapter](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014-v1/GUID-119DBB77-D0DB-4D59-BD2F-29C6D0DBA8E1) in our docs about "Copying Promotions"? On the surface, at least, it looks like exactly what you need.

Comment: Hi Nuno, Thanks a lot for the information. But using this "copy" I can only copy the Promotion within the instances(Live or Preview), but I am looking for a option to copy it within the environments (like: Dev to SIT or Production).