# Copying SmartTarget promotions across environments

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper

We have requirement to copy our SmartTarget promotions across environments.
There is option to export configuration of indexer via doing following actions:

Connected as the "fredhopper" user do:

```
cd /home/fredhopper/fredhopper
./bin/capture-export indexer /tmp/fredhopper-export/DEV-export.zip -i -c
```

Here are the steps to import the Zip file:

1. Copy the Zip file onto the Fredhopper server to refresh, in this case SIT.
2. Stop all Fredhopper instances, i.e. indexer and all query instances
3. Run the capture import tool
4. Run the `fresh-index-to-live` script
5. Start all Fredhopper instances

Connected as the "fredhopper" user do the following.

On the first Fredhopper server (running the indexer) do:

```
./bin/instance indexer stop 
./bin/instance query-live1 stop
```

On the second Fredhopper server do:

```
./bin/instance query-live2 stop
```

On the first Fredhopper server (running the indexer) do:

```
./bin/capture-import indexer /tmp/fredhopper-import/DEV-export.zip 
./bin/fresh-index-to-live indexer
```

On the first Fredhopper server (running the indexer) do:

```
 ./bin/instance indexer start 
 ./bin/instance query-live1 start
```

On the second Fredhopper server do:

```
./bin/instance query-live2 start
```

This question is similar [to this one](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/12948/is-it-possible-to-copy-promotions-from-one-environment-to-other-environment), but I wanted to create new one to explain it in more detail.

What worries me, is that Fredhopper official documentation states that capture-export with `-c` will export "configuration". **Configuration includes `business.xml`, but what worries me is what else does it include (like live attributes, regions, etc...)? What I only want to achieve is export just ST promotions and nothing else if possible.** Has anyone had this requirement before.

PS. I know that there is a way to save (export single promotion via ST GUI, but doing that for couple of hundreds is a lot of clicking :D )
 [image]

Comment: Wouldn't a promotion typically contain references to Tridion items, like keywords, folders or components? How would that work if you import a promotion in another environment?

Comment: My idea is to use webdavs during export/import. You are correct @Quirijn, business.xml has only tcm ids, so creating some custom tool would be great... It might even be good enough for posting for others to use :)

Comment: As long as, if you are using the same CMS with multiple publishing targets with different CD environments then you can export and import to create the new indexer instance it will work

Comment: yes, I am aware of that. We did it to move from staging to live. But this is export/import across environments, so i will have to use webdavs to try to map all objects (folders, templates, components, schemas, publications).... not to mention triggers and other stuff.... :D

Comment: The use case isn't really clear here. Why do you want to copy all Promotions but not all of the configuration around it that support said Promotions? For instance, if you don't have the triggers that they are using -- the Promotions end up being invalid and won't fire.

Comment: well that is exactly my point. I want to use capture-export/capture-import commands but i am not sure if everything will be OK. I guess not, since for example, publication tcms are different on DEV and SIT environments. So i have to find some other way to port data from DEV to SIT.